# Discord bot sends MessageEmbed object twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

This is an embed I made. For some reason, my bot sends it twice. I've tried restarting my PC and even checked for extra terminals...

CODE:

```
bot.on('message', msg=> {
  if ( msg.content === "WhosMyWaifu"){
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    msg.reply(    
        embed.setImage('https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/load-68-more-imagesgrid-view-me-dio-11563057753kl6hlthvsz.png'),
        embed.setColor('RANDOM'),
        embed.setFooter(msg.author.username),
        msg.channel.send(embed));
  }  
})
```

It sends the same thing twice, but when it sends the sound embed, it also says my username and "object, Object"

Comment: I don't know discord, but I would guess it has something to do with calling `msg.reply()` and calling `msg.channel.send()`.

Comment: I  think you are currently replying (msg.reply) and also sending (msg.channel.send) at the same time

Comment: LMAO IM SO DUMB, thank you for making me realize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are replying to the message and then also sending the embed again afterward. You need to only being sending the embed once:

```js
bot.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content === "WhosMyWaifu") {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()  
        .setImage('https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/load-68-more-imagesgrid-view-me-dio-11563057753kl6hlthvsz.png')
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setFooter(msg.author.username)
    msg.channel.send(embed);
}
```